# VB datagridview on duplicate key update

Tags: mysql, datagridview

I am trying to update a row using a file which I upload into Datagridview. It usually works with the standard Insert command, but when trying to update a row where the primary key is the same, I don't know how to write the MySQL command for it.

I tried:

```
dbSQL_query = "INSERT INTO bond_static VALUES (" + addQoute(ID) + ", " + _
                      + _ addQoute(age) + ", " + _
                       addQoute(name) + ", " + _
                      addQoute(gender) + " on duplicate key update (age)= " + ")"
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error code or message?